# Posting image from SharePoint on Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, microsoft-flow, microsoft-teams

I would like to know the best way to have an image on SP to show in a post on Teams.
I have a Flow which pulls a SP list item daily and posts it in Teams. The problem I have is that the images don't show. I can make them an image column or an attachment, either is fine.
I tried html img with src from SP but it doesn't show. I tried html img with src from non-SP site and it works. I tried base64 encoding the image, but it makes the message too large, so it won't post.
How can i get an image from SP onto my Teams post?
Thank you.

EDIT: Adding images
[image: Message in Teams App]
[image: Message in Teams Online]

Comment: I forgot to mention I am sending the message to a Webhook in Teams, so I'm using the Actionable Message format.

Comment: Try this https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/.  I did try this  and was able to get the image to work under: activityImage but not heroImage.

Comment: @SharePointer can you post your image url? I have a feeling the permissions need to be external (so if i can see it). If so, how can I set the images to be external?

Comment: @SharePointer I posted images... It seems to work in Teams Online (firefox) but not on the Teams application.

Comment: Okay great to know it worked.

Comment: Well.... it works in the browser, but we all use the Desktop App, so this wont work. Interesting why this is happening though. I imagine it might have been because my browser session for SP is still active?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Compose` action with the following html:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="URL OF THE IMAGE FILE/ATTACHMENT" />
```

Flow would like something like that:

[image]